# If statement is not working when I pass a Boolean variable to a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm working on Ionic 4, and in one of the pages, I need to display a string according to the gender.

So, the function will take the variable `gen`, and if it is `true` it will return `'Female'` but `'Male'` if it is `false`.

At the moment of implementing it, it only gives me the first case in every value of `gen`(no matter gen is true or false).

I tried the `==` operator, the `not` operator and the `===`.

It happens in other function as wells that return values.

```
displayGender(gen: boolean): string {
 console.log(gen);
 if (gen) {
   console.log(gen);
   return 'Female';
 } else {
   return 'Male';
 }
}
```

I put some logs to see.

For example, in one of my test I sent a `false` value, the console output `false` and then false again, meaning it returns `'Female'`.

Thank you

Comment: can you check type of gen in your function ? `console.log(typeof gen);`

Comment: I did that and it says string, but the variable in the interface is boolean.

Comment: so use it like this, `if(gen == "true")`

Comment: okay, that fixed my problem, thank you so much

Comment: that means that gen is being interpreted as a string - not the boolean as intended

Comment: Do something like this if you want to enter boolean value
`console.log("True ---> ", this.displayGender(true))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your code... just pass the correct argument in the parameter list.

```
displayGender(gen: boolean): string {
 console.log(gen);
 if (gen) {
   console.log(gen);
   return 'Female';
 } else {
   return 'Male';
 }
}

console.log(this.displayGender(false));
```

As per your code a boolean value is expected. you might be passing string value (if yes, then adjust the logic).

```
displayGender(gen: boolean): string {
 console.log(gen);
 if (gen == 'true') {
   console.log(gen);
   return 'Female';
 } else {
   return 'Male';
 }
}

console.log(this.displayGender('false'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the boolean variable is in a string format.

Try this:

```
displayGender(gen: boolean): string {
 console.log(gen);
 if (gen == 'true') {
   console.log(gen);
   return 'Female';
 } else {
   return 'Male';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
displayGender(gen: boolean): string {
 if (gen == "true") {
   return 'Female';
 } else {
   return 'Male';
 }
```

Actually gen is considered as string not boolean. That's why you are facing this issue. Since gen is considered as string so you can simply solve it by comparing it with the string value.